# Automating SQL view exports to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a view written in SQL Server. I need to export the data to Excel so that there are separate Excel files for every possible two letter country code. Files are named "Report - *Country* *Date*.xslx", for example "Report - Australia 06082018.xlsx".

So far I  have just connected the view to Excel and repeated following steps for each country:

1. Change the country code in the SQL view
2. Save the Excel file with a name matching the country in question

There are some 100 different countries, so the work is quite repetitive and tedious. There are also too many rows in the query results to export several countries' data at the same time. Is there a way to automate this process, even just some part of it?

Comment: SSIS is made for this type of thing.  You can create a loop in SSIS and generate an Excel file for every country code

Comment: In addition to @Brad great suggestion, this sounds like a perfect choice for a BI tool to display the data, or a SSRS report.

Comment: I'd go with @scsimon and recommend SSRS with a subscription. You can format the results. SSIS will just plop data in and you can't really format well.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, normally i would recommend SSIS to do this. Its an excellent tool to handle your question. However if you REALLY want to do it in SQL you can do something like this:

**NB's**

> 1. I could only get it to work by using xls excel files.
> 2. It will give you a warning about its not trusted source however you can just click OK
> 3. I havent tested it deeply so there can be errors or fixes that needs to be made :)

**Prestep:** Load sample data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestExcel](
    [CountryCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Names] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Sales] [int] NULL
)

Insert into dbo.TestExcel (CountryCode,Names,Sales)
Values

('DA','Thomas', 10),
('DA','Jens',   20),
('DA','John',   40),
('EN','Mark',   10),
('EN','Adam',   5 )
```

**Step 1:**
Create a stored procedure

```
Create procedure proc_generate_excel_with_columns
(
    @db_name    varchar(100),
    @table_name varchar(100),   
    @file_name  varchar(100),
    @CountryCode varchar(10)
)
as

--Generate column names as a recordset
declare @columns varchar(8000), @sql varchar(8000), @data_file varchar(100)
select 
    @columns=coalesce(@columns+',','')+column_name+' as '+column_name 
from 
    information_schema.columns
where 
    table_name=@table_name
select @columns=''''''+replace(replace(@columns,' as ',''''' as '),',',',''''')

PRINT 'Headers'
PRINT @columns

PRINT 'Create a dummy file to have actual data'
select @data_file=substring(@file_name,1,len(@file_name)-charindex('\',reverse(@file_name)))+'\data_file_'+cast(cast(GETDATE() as date) as nvarchar)+'.xls'

print @data_file

print 'Generate column names in the passed EXCEL file'
set @sql='exec master..xp_cmdshell ''bcp " select * from (select '+@columns+') as t" queryout "'+@file_name+'_'+@CountryCode+cast(cast(GETDATE() as date) as nvarchar)+'.xls" -S "EGC25199\SQL2016" -T -c'''
print @sql
exec(@sql)

print 'Generate data in the dummy file'
set @sql='exec master..xp_cmdshell ''bcp "select * from '+@db_name+'..'+@table_name+' where CountryCode = '''''+@CountryCode+'''''" queryout "'+@data_file+'" -S "EGC25199\SQL2016" -T -c'''
print @sql
exec(@sql)

--Copy dummy file to passed EXCEL file
set @sql= 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''type '+@data_file+' >> "'+@file_name+'_'+@CountryCode+cast(cast(GETDATE() as date) as nvarchar)+'.xls"'''
exec(@sql)

--Delete dummy file 
set @sql= 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''del '+@data_file+''''
exec(@sql)
```

**Step 2:** Execute stored procedure

```
USE [LegOgSpass]
GO

DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @db_name varchar(100) = 'LegOgSpass'
DECLARE @table_name varchar(100) = 'TestExcel'
DECLARE @file_name varchar(100) = 'D:\Test\TestExcel'
DECLARE @CountryCode varchar(10) = 'EN'

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[proc_generate_excel_with_columns] 
   @db_name
  ,@table_name
  ,@file_name
  ,@CountryCode
```

**Result - Picture of Folder**
[image]

**Result of DA**

[image]

**Result of EN**

[image]

Comment: That seems like a useful solution. Maybe I should first try SSIS as it is strongly suggested. Can you recommend some resources to get started with SSIS? I have only used SSMS to query databases and design views. How can I take advantage of SSIS functionalities with existing SQL Server view?

Comment: @Stam1naAndSp33d Create a new Question if you want an answer to this, so others can help.

Answer (score 0):

Python can also help in automating SQL data ->Excel. This sample code creates 4 excel sheets using pyexcelerate.

```
#•pyexcelerate 
import pyexcelerate as px
from datetime import date 
wb = px.Workbook()
ws = wb.new_sheet("Report")
n = date.today()
ReportDate = "{:02.0f}{:02.0f}{}".format(n.day,n.month,n.year)
ws.range("B2", "C3").value = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
Countrylist = ['USA', 'Australia','China','Nigeria']
#"Report - Australia 06082018.xlsx". 
for c in countrylist:
        wb.save("Report -"+c+' '+str(ReportDate)+".xlsx")
```